# Accessing database stored in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans

I want to access the database that I've set up in persistence.xml in Netbeans.

I have some sample code that seems to use an EntityManager and UserTransaction to store a person object in the database, but I'm wondering if I need to use the same thing for a simple SELECT query?

```
@WebServlet(name="CreatePersonServlet", urlPatterns={"/CreatePerson"})
public class CreatePersonServlet extends HttpServlet {

@PersistenceUnit
//The emf corresponding to 
private EntityManagerFactory emf;  

@Resource
private UserTransaction utx;


/** Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException {
    assert emf != null;  //Make sure injection went through correctly.
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {

        //Get the data from user's form            
        String firstName  = (String) request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName   = (String) request.getParameter("surname");
        String address   = (String) request.getParameter("address");
        String dobString   = (String) request.getParameter("dob");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dob = formatter.parse(dobString);
        String email      = (String) request.getParameter("email");
        String phone      = (String) request.getParameter("phone");
        String password   = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        boolean isAdmin = false;


        //Create a person instance out of it
        Customer person = new Customer(firstName, lastName, dob, email, phone, password, isAdmin);

        //begin a transaction
        utx.begin();
        //create an em. 
        //Since the em is created inside a transaction, it is associsated with 
        //the transaction
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        //persist the person entity
        em.persist(person);
        //commit transaction which will trigger the em to 
        //commit newly created entity into database
        utx.commit();

        //Forward to ListPerson servlet to list persons along with the newly
        //created person above
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ListPerson").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    } finally {
        //close the em to release any resources held up by the persistence provider
        if(em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to use a manual connection string to do what I want:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mydb","mydb", "mypassword");

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Customer where Email=? and Password=?");
```

Is there an easier way to access the database, since it's already set up in persistence?

Comment: Using JPA to fetch objects from the database is infinitely simpler than doing plain JDBC you know, especially if you already have the entity. It can be as simple as an em.find(Customer.class, idOfCustomer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual way is define [NamedQuery](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named) in your entity class because it becomes than database agnostic and you can benefit from caching. So try something like

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQery(name = "customerByMailAndPassword"
               query = "select * from Customer where Email=? and Password=?")
})
@Entity
public class Customer {}
```

Then use it like this

```
Customer c = em.createNamedQuery("customerByMailAndPassword")
    .setParameter(1, "mail@mail.com")
    .setParameter(2, "psswd")
    .getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you want to do. If you want a list of Customer objects, use createQuery() to create a query that'll return a list of Customer.

If you really want to just arbitrary SQL, ask your entity manager to execute a native query.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery('select foo from bar');
```

You might want to read all of http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html to see what it can do.